# Audio not working on Sony Vaio Pro 13. HDA Intel PCH. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, vaio

I've tried unmuting alsamixer, updating alsa, and force stopping pulseaudio. So far I can't figure it out.

```
~$ lspci -nn|egrep 'ultimedia|udio|sound|AC97|ac97|EMU'
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
```

Answer (score 1):

following are steps I followed and it worked in my  Laptop OS ubuntu 12.04

1. `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` 
   add a line here

   `options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0xffff,0xfff2`
2. `sudo vi /etc/modules`
   add a line i.e

   ```
   audio driver name
   ```

   in my case it was

   ```
   snd_hda_intel
   ```
3. now reboot the system